# Uniform continuity and boundedness of higher order derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, derivatives, continuity

Any hint on how to solve the following problem is highly appreciated:

> Let $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a twice-differentiable function such that:
>
> - $f$ is uniformly continuous
> - $f''$ is bounded (e.g.: $|f''| \leq M$)
>
> then, show that $f'$ must be bounded.

also:

> Can this result be generalized? If $f$ is an n-times differentiable and uniformly continuous function on $\Bbb R$ such that $f^{(n)}$ is bounded, then is $f'$ bounded?

**My Attempt**

So far I have just been able to try the first problem, however, working on it I realized that the n-th derivative and the first derivative may be too distant to exchange important information on their reciprocal behavior. Anyway, I tried by contradiction:
$$
\exists \{x_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N} : f'(x_{n+1}) = f'(x_{n}) + (n+1)
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty}|f'(x_n)| = +\infty
$$
From this result (which can be easily proved using Darboux Property), I deduced:
$$
\frac{n}{M} \leq |x_{n+1} - x_{n}|, \forall n \in \Bbb N
$$
and I also know that $f'$ must be M-Lipschitz. Therefore, I think no other information can be collected studying the second derivative. My problem is with uniform continuity, in fact I do not know what has to be used: uniform differentiability, mean value theorem, ...

Answer (score 1):

Assume by contradiction that $f'$ is unbounded and wlog there is a sequence $x_n \to \infty, f'(x_n)=n$ (taking if needed $f(-x), -f(x), -f(-x)$ which satisfy same hypothesis allows this)

Then by MVT one has $|f'(x_n)-f'(y)| \le M|x-y|$ so for $y \in [x_n, x_n+1]$ one has $f'(y) \ge f'(x_n)-M \ge n/2, n \ge 2M$ but then by MVT again $|f(x_n)-f(y)| \ge n|x_n-y|/2, x_n \le y \le x_n+1$ and that contradicts uniform continuity on the reals (as by uniform continuity there is $\delta>0$ st $|f(x)-f(y)| \le 1$ for $|x-y| \le \delta$ and for $y=x_n+\min (\delta,1)$ we would have $n\min (\delta,1)/2 \le 1$ for every $n \ge 2M$

I am not seeing an obvious way to generalize this even for the case where $|f'''(x)| \le M$ but at least the original problem is solved